# How can I create system image file from a bunch of backup files?

Tags: boot, backup, filesystems, iso-image, liveusb

I have a bunch of system backup files, which I need to create a bootable drive or a live image on a flash drive.

I tried to search for all the available post online for creating a system image file, most of them were about ISO file and creating bootable file is about flashing ISO file using some software utilities like Rufus or Etcher.

Some information on all these files: 
[file_list](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gZ5m5.png)

I am looking for some leads on how can I create a bootable drive or flash all these files on a drive?

Comment: Bootable drive to boot what and why?

Comment: It has a snapshot of the Linux environment. I want to create a live usb, where I can replicate the same environment.

Answer (score 0):

The files listed seem like a clonezilla backup.

I would go download clonezilla bootable ISO

https://www.clonezilla.org/downloads.php

1. Make a bootable CD/DVD/USB/etc from the downloads
2. Boot from it.
3. Mount the external hdd with file on it

from a terminal window:

su

mount /dev/whatever /home/partimag

4. Activate clonezilla
5. Restore image to device
6. Set destination
7. restore the image to built in hdd.
8. Boot from it see what happens
9. Report error messages.

---

Alternatively if you want to make something bootable to restore from.

1. Get large external hdd.
2. Use any of the many tools to take an ISO and make the hdd bootable from it.  That should create a small partition.
3. Create another partition, if necessary resize 1st partition.  It can be any linux file system or even NTFS.
4. Copy your image to the 2nd partition
5. Now when you boot from it clonezilla should automatically bring up the desktop.
6. Then run clonezilla normally to restore the image.

Comment: I am on it, will let you know if it doesn't works.